# Python Crash Course 2nd Edition Problem 5-10

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement

I am a Python rookie attempting to complete the following problem:

> > Do the following to create a program that simulates how websites
> > ensure that everyone has a unique username.
> >
> > Make a list of five or more usernames called current_users. Make
> > another list of five usernames called new_users. Make sure one or two
> > of the new usernames are also in the current_users list. Loop through
> > the new_users list to see if each new username has already been used.
> > If it has, print a message that the person will need to enter a new
> > username. If a username has not been used, print a message saying that
> > the username is available.
> >
> > Make sure your comparison is case insensitive. If 'John' has been used, 'JOHN' should not be accepted.

This is the answer that I came up with:

```
current_users = ['kenny1', 'kenny2', 'kenny3', 'kenny4', 'kenny5']
current_users_upper = [user.upper() for user in current_users]
new_users = ['kenny5', 'kenny6', 'kenny7', 'kenny8', 'kenny9']

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user.upper() in current_users_upper:
        print(f"The username {new_user} is already taken.  Please choose another username")
    else:
        print(f"The username {new_user} is available.")
```

I tested this code by changing the username 'kenny5' to UPPER case, lower case, Title case, and RaNdOm case, and it code catches 'kenny5'.  I do not know how this code is correct.  To me, we would need to run another for loop to check the new_users list with the current_users list to test whether 'KENNY5' is being used again.  Something like:

```
current_users = ['kenny1', 'kenny2', 'kenny3', 'kenny4', 'kenny5']
current_users_upper = [user.upper() for user in current_users]
new_users = ['kenny5', 'kenny6', 'kenny7', 'kenny8', 'kenny9']

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user.upper() in current_users_upper:
        print(f"The username {new_user} is already taken.  Please choose another username")
    elif new_user in current_users:
        print(f"The username {new_user} is already taken.  Please choose another username")
    else:
        print(f"The username {new_user} is available.")
```

I also checked the solutions manual and this is an accepted answer.  Is this answer thorough enough?  Thank you!

Comment: Hi. The problem statement doesn't require you to actually ask and read in a new user name. It just asks to check once. You are right of course that a website dialog that lets you create a username should keep asking you for a new username until you pick one that's available.

Comment: By converting the current users to uppercase and each new user to uppercase, you've already made the matching case insensitive. Your first approach is correct, the first elif from the second approach will never be reached, as the first if statement will run when that elif should run.

Comment: Hi @cadolphs.  Thank you for the response.  I remember bashing my head in a specific problem because it wasn't specific enough and I ran into a tangent researching how to answer the problem.  This is another example of that.  Thank you!

Comment: Hi B Remmelzwaal.  I was thinking I would have to run additional elif statements, but your explanation made total sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not know how this code is correct. To me, we would need to run another for loop to check the new_users list with the current_users list to test whether 'KENNY5' is being used again. Something like:

If you did that, you would be doing a case-sensitive comparison with the current users. But if your program has reached the line `elif new_user in current_users:` that means that the case-insensitive comparison returned no matches.

If the case-insensitive comparison returned no matches, then the case-sensitive version is guaranteed to also return no matches. A case-sensitive comparison is more restrictive in what it considers a match than a case-insensitive comparison.